# Long-Term EMG studies

Tags: muscles, data, signal-processing

I am having trouble differentiating onset/offset of muscle activation. Is there anyone in the field has a specific way to set the threshold for both time and magnitude?

Comment: Can you give more information about the system you are working in? What species? Indwelling or surface electrodes? etc.

Comment: I am using OpenBCI with surface electrodes  [link](http://shop.openbci.com/products/openbci-32-bit-board-kit?variant=784651699) I am testing on average human adults.